# How to get rid of UUID for distribution.plist?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, enterprise

Using an enterprise account I want to be able to export my iOS, Xcode app so that people within my organization can beta test. Unfortunately, after I export, a specific UUID is added to the distribution.plist. Due to this, I am not able to distribute my app. Any suggestions on how to make it so any UUID can test the app.

Comment: You should archive and then export a signed Enterprise build and distribute that.

Comment: But when I do that there is a hardcoded UUID in the distribution.plist? How can people test if there is a specified UUID?

Comment: So you are doing archive->Distribute->Enterprise->Automatically manage signgin->Export?  Are you talking about the UUID key in the profile?  That is just the UUID of the provisioning profile. It isn't a device UDID.  How are you distributing the ipa file?